# evidence of email sent from Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a customer who is disputing whether an email was actually sent to them.
We sent this email using File drop automation from Marketing cloud

I can see in the tracking that the email got delivered and was also opened. The email address is also correct.

Sorry for the strange question, but is there any more evidence that can be provided here.
Are there email logs saved in .zip format in Marketing Cloud.
Also to future proof this, can we have a .pdf email 'sent either via FD automation or a Journey' saved maybe in our data warehouse when they are sent?

Answer (score 2):

You could ask Support for logs. They'd possibly be able to give you quite a bit of detail if you made the case for them to go to the effort, but I don't think you'll get anything more definitive in terms of "evidence" than what's available in the [Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract_output.htm&type=5). The Open extract should give you time, location(ish), IP address, device etc of the Open.

SFMC can provision "Email Archiving" that saves .eml or .pdf copies of everything going through the MTAs, but it's priced to say "we don't want to sell this or support it". You can use the BCC feature to send copies of emails sent to an email address of your choosing. This doubles your Super Message usage, but is likely still far more economical than Email Archiving. Neither would help you retrospectively, though, and neither provides "proof" of delivery. They just provide detail of the content that was sent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree i think the detail in tracking extract should be sufficient evidence. i might explore the bcc option to see whether our usage limits will allow it. Thank you.